# Align widget not working on FlutterSwitch (package:flutter_switch)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image]

I want to align the switch button to Top right side (marked in the picture)

What i did,

I tried FlutterSwitch wrap with container and set aligment. It  didn't work.
then i tried Positioned, It also didn't work

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: FlutterSwitch(
                  value: isSwitchOn,
                  onToggle: (value) {
                    setState(() {
                      isSwitchOn = value;
                    });
                  },
                  width: 60.0,
                  height: 40.0,
                  toggleSize: 28.0,
                  activeToggleColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 113, 82, 173),
                  inactiveToggleColor: const Color(0xFF2F363D),
                  activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 32, 82),
                  inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                  activeIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.nightlight_round,
                    color: Color(0xFFF8E3A1),
                  ),
                  inactiveIcon: const Icon(
                    Icons.wb_sunny,
                    color: Color(0xFFF8E3A1),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the `FlutterSwitch` widget with the [IntrinsicWidth](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicWidth-class.html) widget and it should work. Also, use `Alignment.centerRight` instead of `Alignment.topRight`.

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Align(
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: IntrinsicWidth(
                  child: FlutterSwitch(
                    value: isSwitchOn,
                    onToggle: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        isSwitchOn = value;
                      });
                    },
                    width: 60.0,
                    height: 40.0,
                    toggleSize: 28.0,
                    activeToggleColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 113, 82, 173),
                    inactiveToggleColor: const Color(0xFF2F363D),
                    activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 32, 82),
                    inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
                    activeIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.nightlight_round,
                      color: Color(0xFFF8E3A1),
                    ),
                    inactiveIcon: const Icon(
                      Icons.wb_sunny,
                      color: Color(0xFFF8E3A1),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

What you were doing was like a shortcut, instead of doing that wrap the widget, and also use flexible or expanded to make the widget more responsive

```
Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Flexible(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15, vertical: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: IntrinsicWidth(
            child: FlutterSwitch(
              value: isSwitchOn,
              onToggle: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  isSwitchOn = value;
                });
              },
              width: 60.0,
              height: 40.0,
              toggleSize: 28.0,
              activeToggleColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 113, 82, 173),
              inactiveToggleColor: const Color(0xFF2F363D),
              activeColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 49, 32, 82),
              inactiveColor: Colors.grey,
              activeIcon: const Icon(
                Icons.nightlight_round,
                color: Color(0xFFF8E3A1),
              ),
              inactiveIcon: const Icon(
                Icons.wb_sunny,
                color: Color(0xFFF8E3A1),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
);
```